# Stabilisation by feedback

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm just going through some questions about stability from my course. The questions relate to determining for which $F$ the matrix $A−BF$ is asymptotically stable.

The question which I am confused is:

Determine for which F the matrix A-BF is stable, where

A=\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array}

and

B=\begin{array}{ccc}
0 \\
1  \\
\end{array}

In the lecture notes and some of the other questions on problem sheets the lecturer always considers for which values of F, $det(A-BF-\lambda I)$ is stable. But in the question above he only considers $det(A-BF)$ and I am unsure why - as it gives a different result than when considering $det(A-BF-\lambda I)$.

Comment: The pair $(A,B)$ is not stabilizable, so no $F$ works.

Comment: @A.G. The solutions say that for any $F1∈ R$ and $F2 > 2$ the matrix $A − BF$ is stable

Comment: $A-BF=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_1 & F_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1+F_1 & F_2\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. The unstable eigenvalue $2$ cannot be changes by any $F$.

Comment: @A.G. my apologies, there was a typo in B, corrected now.

Comment: Changing the sign does not help, it is still  not stabilizable. Maybe $B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$? Then any $F_1$ and $F_2>2$ is the answer. Think that the system is diagonal, and in your case you can control only the first, already stable, subsystem. The second subsystem is unstable and uncontrollable.

Comment: @A.G. Yeh that's the correct matrix, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closed loop system matrix is
$$
A-BF=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}F_1 & F_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\-F_1 & 2-F_2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It has two eigenvalues $-1$ and $2-F_2$ (easy to see as the matrix is triangular, so the eigenvalues are on the main diagonal). To be stable both must have negative real parts. The first one is no problem, the second one should satisfy 
$$
2-F_2<0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad F_2>2.
$$